# Python - Read Strings from Text File

Tags: python, string, text

so I want to use data from a certain line of a text file in an if statement.  This is what I have, and even if line 2 of the text file is set to 'off' or 'on', nothing happens.

```
gamestatus = linecache.getline('C:/directory/gameinfo.txt', 2) 
if gamestatus == 'off': 
    print("Test") 
elif gamestatus == 'on': 
    print("Another test")
```

But, if I did something like 
    print(gamestatus) 
but not in a an if statement, it prints 'off' or 'on'.  Any ideas?

Comment: Show us a sample of the text file

Answer (score 0):

Line cache.getLine returns the line ending along with the text. String the line ending off like:

```
gamestatus = linecache.getline('Password.txt', 1).rstrip('\n')
```

You can use rstrip() without args to remove all trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
LINE_NUMBER = 2

with open('C:/directory/gameinfo.txt') as f:
    for i in range(LINE_NUMBER - 1):
        f.readline()
    gamestatus = f.readline().rstrip()
if gamestatus == 'off': 
    print("Test") 
elif gamestatus == 'on': 
    print("Another test")
```